# Миграция Laravel could not find driv

Tags: php

Работаю в Sublime Text, нужно установить миграцию с БД MySQL. Ошибка "could not find drivers". В интернете смотрела разные варианты решения, не получается ни одно.  Помогите пожалуйста!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

phh -m
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приложите вывод `php -m`

Comment: Приложила php -m

Comment: У вас драйвер для связи называется mysqlnd, а не MySQL. Либо поставьте новый, либо прописывайте новый в настройках ‘driver’ => ‘mysqli’. Лучше сделать апгрейд.

Comment: Извините, вы не подскажите как это сделать. Пожалуйста. Я только начинаю изучать. Где надо поменять или переустановить?